# Classical synonym for "Crackpot"

Tags: etymology

A serious question: I don't think there is a "classical" (i.e., Greek- or Latin-based) synonym for for the English word "crackpot", a person with crazy ideas.  But if there were, would it be "schizoceramic" or "schistoceramic" or something else?

Comment: 'Crackpot' is a slang word (probably from 'pot' as an old slang word for 'head'), so you can't assume it can be literally translated 'back' into Latin or Greek.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/6318566-people-think-you-re-crazy-if-you-talk-about-things-they

Comment: Looking at things like "schizoceramic" seems to me like a way too literal approach to finding a word like this. Have you looked in an English/Greek or English/Latin dictionary, or a Latin or Greek thesaurus? "Ass" is technically from Latin (*asinus*), although it's an old borrowing, and I think it could be used with a similar meaning to "crackpot" in some contexts.

Comment: A daft idea is often described as 'it won't hold water' meaning it cannot contain the problems or variables under consideration. Presumably that is the sense of a 'cracked pot' or 'crackpot' idea. And hence the outlook of a 'crackpot' person.

Answer (score 1):

**Lunatic** fits the bill, as it's from a [Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lunaticus) word originally:

> An extremely foolish or eccentric person.
>
> Middle English: from Old French lunatique, from late Latin lunaticus, from Latin luna ‘moon’ (from the belief that changes of the moon caused intermittent insanity).
> <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/lunatic)</sub>

Comment: Lunatic is a rather general term, whereas a crackpot can be completely sane in all respects other than their specific beliefs such as the world is flat or Shakespeare didn't write his plays.

Comment: So how many people have called you "Yanny" today?

Answer (score 0):

There is the humorous coinage 'psychoceramicist': https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josiah_S._Carberry